# IPython autocompletion does not work for nested dynamic attributes

Tags: python, pandas, ipython

In this example, IPython cannot autocomplete nested dynamic attributes:

```py
class Klass:

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        if attr == 'other':
            return Klass()
        else:
            raise ValueError()
    
    def __dir__(self):
        return ['other']

a = Klass()

# autocompletes
a.other

# does not autocomplete (when typing a.other.oth)
a.other.other
```

But nested attribute autocompletion seems to work with a multi-level DataFrame:

```py
import pandas as pd

col = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('foo', 'AAA'), 
                                 ('foo', 'BBB'), 
                                 ('bar', 'AAA'), 
                                 ('bar', 'BBB')])

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=col)

# This autocompletes:
df.foo.AAA
```

Why does it work with the DataFrame and not with my class ?

Comment: This actually works for me.  I can do `a.other.other.other....` and it keeps filling in.   IPython 7.33.0, Python 3.9

Comment: Just so you are all aware, I'm pretty sure Ipython autocompletion works in these cases **by actually calling the method**.

Comment: But yes, I can also report, this is working for me, IPython version 8.10.0, Python 3.11

Comment: @Tom indeed, I made other trials (python 3.8.8):  
IPython console (8.11.0) : works; 
Spyder console (5.4.2) : does not work; 
Jupyter qtconsole (5.4.0) : works; 
Jupyter notebook (6.5.3) : works but not with VSCode extension.